# Twitter-bootstrap div grid arrangement based on specific requirement

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've this twitter-bootstrap grid structure.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">A</div><div class="col-lg-4">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">C</div><div class="col-lg-8">D</div>
</div>
```

If I reduce the screen size, the output will be:

```
A
B
C
D
```

My question is, is it possible to let the output become

```
A
B
D
C
```

in smaller size and become

```
A  B
C  D
```

in desktop screen size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used flexible box solution for the output. Reordered the divs `C` and `D` based on the screen size < 768px. Check the browser compatibility table here: [**Can I use Flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .reorder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .second {
    order: 1;
  }
  .first {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row reorder">
    <div class="col-lg-4 first">C</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 second">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want in smaller displays have the output as

```
A B
C D
```

because as smaller display you have, as more narrow your width becomes, meaning for best performance, you should place elements rather in the column. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pavLkd59/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`col-lg-*` is for large screens
`col-md-*` is for medium screens
`col-sm-*` is for small screens
`col-xs-*` is for extra small screens

define others to achieve what you are expecting and wrap all `col-*` in one `row` class.