# Bootstrap-columns over rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

On a small device, I want:

```
-----
| A |
-----
| B |
-----
| C |
-----
```

But on a medium+ device, I want:

```
----------
| A || C |
----------
|   B    |
----------
```

I've tried the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-md-push-6">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">C</div>    
</div>
```

But B and C won't shift up or down, they only get an offset to the left or right.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it impossible?

Comment: I think `col-md-push-6` should be `col-md-push-12` for B?

Comment: @Lyall, that just shifts the cell further to the right. I think it's impossible to push/pull cell's that make a total of more than 12.

Comment: There is always another way which I used before, which is to insert a col (duplicate of col C) between A and B which is set to `hidden-xs` (doesn't show in extra small view) and set the current C col to be `visible-xs hidden-md` so it only shows in extra small. Using this (or a variation, using hidden and visible) enabled me to create completely different layouts for different screen sizes by showing/hiding different things.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that would result in generating a piece of content twice (I know, it still comes from 1 source). It doesn't make the document structure simpler ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter-bootstrap div grid arrangement based on specific requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555732/twitter-bootstrap-div-grid-arrangement-based-on-specific-requirement)

Answer (score 0):

This will work i think..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">C</div>    
</div>
```