# Layout using Bootstrap push and pull classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I ran into a strange issue when trying to use simple Bootstrap push and pull classes to reorder columns.

In my case, I want to do this for mobile (I know, mobile first, this is how the HTML is written):

---

### | 1 |

### | 2 |

### | 3 |

### | 4 |

For the desktop (md & lg), I want this layout:

[image]

However, this is as far as I have gotten into realizing my goal:

[image]

I am aware of other questions very similar to this one, but none of them are helpful in my case. The most relevant to my case is this question, but it has yet to be answered: [Bootstrap-colums over rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112717/bootstrap-colums-over-rows)

EDIT:

In light of @choz answer, here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-8 carousel-header">
    <div class="example-div double">
      1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="example-div">
      2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 no-padding col-md-push-8">

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="example-div">
          3
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="example-div">
          4
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

@choz, your answer doesn't work because the layout has to be in the numbered order as specified in the question for mobile.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer since It's misleading. Actually there's another approach by using `hidden-md` and `visible-md`. But you need to create 2 different layouts. And for reference there might be useful from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555732/twitter-bootstrap-div-grid-arrangement-based-on-specific-requirement

Comment: Nathan check my answer if that you're looking for thanks.

Comment: Thanks @choz, but that question is only partially relevant. I did see that when looking for an answer before asking. The reason that doesn't work for my case is that is doesn't have the col-md-12 separating the 3 & 4 divs from their desired location. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

try this for medium and large screens. Then it should stack up as you like in smaller screens:

```
<div id="notSmartphone">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 carousel-header">
    <div class="example-div double">
       1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="col-md-12 row">
       <div class="example-div">
         3
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-12 row">
       <div class="example-div">
          4
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 row">
     <div class="example-div">
        2
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

For the smartphone view, you can have something like this which can have `display:none;` for larger screens:

```
<div id="smartphone">
<div class="col-md-12 row">
   <div class="example-div">
      1
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 row">
   <div class="example-div">
      2
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 row">
   <div class="example-div">
      3
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 row">
   <div class="example-div">
      4
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Use media query like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    #smartphone {display:block;}
    #notSmartphone {display:none;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 641px) {
    #smartphone {display:none;}
    #notSmartphone {display:block;}
}
```

Comment: He needs the number in order for mobile platform.

Comment: Indeed. This also doesn't follow DRY :/

Comment: Did you try the code? check it out [here](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/GpeENW?editors=110)

Comment: Yes, I did try it. Still, the code requires duplicating data in the DOM, not something that I am a fan of doing..

Answer (score 0):

Try This code. I hope this will help you.

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-8 carousel-header">
    <div class="example-div double">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding hidden-xs">

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="example-div">
          3
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="example-div">
          4
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="example-div">
      2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding visible-xs">

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="example-div">
          3
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="example-div">
          4
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is using hidden-{vp} to hide duplicate data on different screen sizes. No offense, but this does not follow DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You can view from my example.

Hope you learn something from this

HTML

```
<div class="row" style="
    text-align: center;
">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
    /* height: 29%; */
    padding-bottom: 3%;
">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="
    background-color: orange;
">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="
    background-color: pink;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
         <div class="col-lg-12" style="
    background-color: yellow;
">
             2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result

[image]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/o023dq4n/1/)

Comment: Like @choz's answer, this answer removes the desired order of 1,2,3,4 on mobile.

Comment: so u want this layout fit in mobile?

Comment: can u draw some image,what is the layout u want to achieve exactly in mobile/desktop. thanks.

Comment: My desired layouts are in my question. For mobile, I want the divs in the number order, on a desktop, I want the order specified in the screen shot.